# PHP - Cannot acces to public static method of some class from another file

Tags: php, class, server-side

I'm trying to access to public static method inside of php class save in separate file from another file but I getting the error

> "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost/web/test.php"

Model.php

```
<?php
class Model
{
    public static function mensaje()
    {
        return "Mensaje";
    }
}
```

test.php

```
<?php
$mensaje = Model::mensaje();
echo $mensaje;
```

If I put the Model class in the same file of test.php work perfectly, but not when I put in separate files.

Model.php and test.php are in the same directory.

How can I access propertly to static method from other file?

Comment: Are you include Model.php file?

Comment: Just because a Model.php file exists, doesn't that mean it's automagically included in your test.php, unles you're using an autoloader

Comment: public static function in php are not global for entire project?

Answer (score 2):

In `test.php` you'll need to `include` or `require` the Model file so it knows where `Model` is defined:

```
<?php
require_once('Model.php');
$mensaje = Model::mensaje();
echo $mensaje;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php

Answer (score 0):

You just need to include or require the file in your current file you are using

```
 <?php
 Require'test.php';
 //Or you can use  
 Include'test.php'; 
 // both will work 

 ?>
```